# Deploy resources only if a file exists in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

I have a requirement where I have to deploy resources only if a certain file exists at a certain location otherwise it will skip the resource.

Like here is the code to deploy a certain identity provider in certain AWS accounts. Along with this identity provider (say abc) many other identity providers are also deployed from the same main.tf file so all has to be here. The only challenge is while deploying the IAM layer for any accounts we will only deploy this certain resource only if `abc-${var.aws_account}.xml` file exists in the filepath in
`saml_metadata_document` part. If it does not exists in the path it will simply ignore the resource creation and will go ahead with the rest of the code.

```
resource "aws_iam_saml_provider" "xyz" {
    name                   = "abc-${var.aws_account}"
    saml_metadata_document =  "${file("${path.module}/metadata/abc-${var.aws_account}.xml")}"
}
```

### Folder Structure

```
IAM-Module
  |
  main.tf
  variables.tf
  metadata
     |
     abc-127367223.xml
     abc-983297832.xml
     abc-342374384.xml
```

How can a conditional check be put in Terraform 0.11 to check the file exists?

Comment: If you are definitely unable to switch to Terraform 0.12 and are thus only interested in 0.11 answers then you should tag your question with `terraform0.11`. If not then you should remove the 0.11 references and accept the current answer.

Answer (score 1):

`count` can be used to create an array of resources instead of just a single resource, so setting count = 0 will create an array of resources of length 0, effectively disabling the resource.

```
resource "aws_iam_saml_provider" "xyz" { 
   name = "abc-${var.aws_account}" 
   saml_metadata_document = "${file("${path.module}/metadata/abc-${var.aws_account}.xml")}" 
   count = fileexists("${path.module}/metadata/abc-${var.aws_account}.xml") ? 1 : 0
}
```

NOTE You will need access to `fileexists` which only exists in 0.12

Comment: I don't think that `fileexists` exists in terraform 0.11.

Comment: Hm yes. It will be hard to get your logic to work with out it IMHO

Comment: And upgrade is not an option?

Comment: You could use an external data source to check for the existence of it. It's much more complex a solution though. Or you could just not check for the file and have it fail if there's no downside to Terraform plan/apply failing if the file doesn't yet exist.

Comment: We are already using AWS as a provider,i don't know if we can also add azure as a provider for terraform to go and query the existence of the metadata file in azure ad.

Comment: secondly we also do a rollout for all the aws accounts we are using the same code, so its not a one time run for which i could have used a python of shell to invoke the right terraform script based on the condition

Comment: Upgrade is definitely not an option considering that we have tons of code already written in terraform 11

Comment: if somehow i can read the filenames from the specified path and store the values in a list variable that might work ,after that i can do a check using ternary operator and deploy the resources if required

Comment: I am not entirely sure this works anymore if the resource uses the file in the deployment. Even thought the count will be set to 0, Terraform errors out because the file referenced in `saml_metadata_document` above does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If it is allowed. Instead of existence of the file, use the file size. If file size is zero, then do not create a resource, otherwise create.

```
data "local_file" "hoge" {
  filename = "${path.module}/hoge"
}

resource "null_resource" "hoge" {
  count = length(data.local_file.hoge.content) > 0 ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
cat "${path.module}/${data.local_file.hoge.filename}"
EOF
  }
}
```